# Select rows based on values in two columns where order of name and surname is not important in MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have in MS SQL Server table like below:

```
col1             | col2
----------------------------
Adam Nowak PHU   | Nowak Adam
AAR Kowal Jan    | Kowal Jan
Tomasz Gut       | Juk Anna
```

And I would like to select only these rows where:

- in col1 I have value from col2 + something (nevermind before or after value)
- Be aware that order of name and surname is not important so Jan Kowal is the same that Kowal Jan

So as a result I need something like below, so only first and second rows because there are in col1 value from col2 + something else and order of name and surname is not important:

[image]

Currently I used query like below, but my query does not take into account that order of name and surname is not important and for my code Jan Kowal and Kowal Jan are different persons.

```
where upper(col1) like '%' + upper(col2) + '%'
```

How can I do taht in MS SQL Server? Could you modify my code or suggest your own ?

Comment: that's bad design , because "Adam Nowak" and "Nowak Adam" are two different people , you can't distinguish which is firstname which last name.

Comment: but I need to check whether value from col2 is in any configuration in col1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do two like and use substrings of the name if the names are all with only first name and last name.
Otherwise, you need to use REGEXP.

```
WHERE
  upper(col1) LIKE '%' + substring(upper(col2), 1, CHARINDEX(' ',col2)-1) + '%'
AND
  upper(col1) LIKE '%' + substring(upper(col2), CHARINDEX(' ',col2)+1, LEN(col2)) + '%'
```

Comment: Great! It works Timothy, htank you! I gave you best answer!

Comment: Glad that it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `STRING_SPLIT` in a subquery to split `col2` and compare:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM YourTable t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(t.col2, ' ') s
    WHERE t.col1 LIKE '%' + s.value + '%'
)
```